# Problema no System.Data.SqlClient ao atualizar para o aspnet 5 core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Atualizei todo meu projeto para o aspnet 5 core pois estava usando o dnx vnext e aparentemente funcionou tudo certinho, porém efetuando testes observei que alguns valores não vinham corretos e ao debugar percebi que o array de parâmetros SqlParameter não está pegando os valores, por exemplo se eu tiver um array com 5 parâmetros e nele conter parâmetros do tipo int ele popula caso contrário não e creio que seja alguma inconsistência da lib System.Data.SqlClient, alguém sabe algo a respeito?
No visual studio fica sublinhado, mostrando a seguinte mensagem:

```
Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy.
```

Esse é o meu project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.0.0",
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
"System.Data.Common": "4.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0"
},

 "tools": {
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-dnxcore50+net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"        
  ]
 }
},

"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
  "configProperties": {
    "System.GC.Server": true
  }
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},

"scripts": {
  "_comment": "dotnet bundle",
  "precompile": [ "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
  "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
  "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath%     --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
},

"tooling": {
  "defaultNamespace": "meuprojeto"
} 
}
```

Comment: Há alguma referência a `System.Web.Mvc` no `references` do seu projeto?

Comment: Fiz um find no Entire Solution por "System.Web.Mvc" não me retornou nada!

Comment: Por exemplo se eu fizer algo como:
    var parameters = new[]
                  {
                      new SqlParameter("@id", 1),
                      new SqlParameter("@nome", "Diogo"),
                      new SqlParameter("@idade", 30),
                      new SqlParameter("@email", "diogo@gmail.com)
                  };
Ele só popula o id e a idade, estou achando muito estranho esse comportamento

Comment: Já experimentou forçar o tipo do parâmetro? `var parametro = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);`, depois `parametro.Value = "diogo@gmail.com"`?

Comment: Eu fiz um teste agora imprimindo o valor dentro de um loop do SqlParameter, eu consigo ler o valor mais se posicionar o mouse em cima não consigo ver o valor então creio que seja um bug do visual studio, irei continuar os testes, tanto é que todo o código relacionado ao sql fica sublinhado em verde no meu fonte.